# $rootScope tracking a model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and am trying to use $rootScope.  I have values that have been selected from a (dynamically generated) options element.  I want to render them at a different route.  The selection options are referred to by 'ng-model' in the html, and there are four distinct ng-models that I want to grab. the models are key value pairs and I want want only the keys.

How can I grab the key of this selectedItem and store it to the $rootScope to use in another controller?

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem4" ng-change="calc2()">
        <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v">{{k}}</option>
    </select>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('FFTrades.tradeanalyzer', [])

.controller('TradesController', function($scope, TradesDataFactory) {

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.selectedItem1 = 0;
    $scope.selectedItem2 = 0;

    $scope.getPlayerData = function() {
        // getting this from the services.
        TradesDataFactory.getPlayerInfo().then(function(playerInfo) {
            $scope.data.playerInfo = playerInfo;
            //console.log($scope.data.playerInfo);
            //["Matt Forte : 17", "Anderson : 16", "Jamaal Charles : 16", "Eddie Lacy : 15", "Andre Ellington : 14", "LeSean McCoy : 14", "Marshawn Lynch : 14", "Tre Mason : 13", "Latavius Murray : 13", "Rashad Jennings : 12", "Alfred Morris : 12", "Jonathan Stewart : 12", "Doug Martin : 12", "Chris Ivory : 12"]
        }).catch(function(error) {
            //console.error(error)
        })
    }


    $scope.calc = function() {
        $scope.calculatedValue1 = Number($scope.selectedItem1);
        if($scope.selectedItem2){
                $scope.calculatedValue1 = Number($scope.selectedItem1) + Number($scope.selectedItem2);

        }

    }

    $scope.calc2 = function() {
        $scope.calculatedValue2 = Number($scope.selectedItem3);
        if ($scope.selectedItem4) {

        $scope.calculatedValue2 = Number($scope.selectedItem3) + Number($scope.selectedItem4);
        };

    }

    $scope.getPlayerData();

});
```

service:

```
angular.module('FFTrades.services', [])
    .factory('TradesDataFactory', function($http) {

        var getPlayerInfo = function() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/scrape'
            }).then(function(resp) {
                //console.log(resp.data);
                return resp.data
            });
        };

        return {
            getPlayerInfo: getPlayerInfo
        }
    });
```

Comment: rootScope is not meant for that, use a service to share data and methods in various parts of the app

Comment: OK, how would I do that in the service? I'm going to include my controller code for clarity's sake.